# A word for decorative cords on uniforms

Tags: word-request

I remember reading a word containing *T-S-L* that describes ornamental cords or brushes that decorate uniforms, perhaps curtains and the like. I thought it was *tassle but came up empty. Which word am I thinking of?

PS: It is *tassel*. I am just an idiot. Wiktionary has a picture

[image: no comment]

Comment: The cords themselves aren't tassels. The flared-out threads at the end are.

Comment: Those are not (all?) military tassels. They are on end of curtain pulls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [**piping**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/piping) <sub>(Cambridge Dictionary)</sub>

*- a folded strip of cloth, often enclosing a cord, used to decorate the edges of clothes or furniture*

In the context of "decorative clothing", the idea is that the strip of cloth is folded into what looks like a thin ***pipe*** or ***tube***. Note that in a culinary context, you might decorate a cake with sugar and/or cream-based "piping" *using* a "piping bag" (a fabric bag containing material forced out through a pipe, a bit like a [grease gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grease_gun_(tool))).

***Tassels*** are tufts of loosely hanging (decorative) threads or cords, whereas ***piping*** is securely attached / stitched throughout its length on to the main bulk of the thing being decorated (clothes, chair covers, curtains, etc.).

Comment: I am a 100 percent certain that it started with *t*, and this is important because I want to compare Ger *Zottel*. It is *tassel*, I had searched *tassle*. Sorry, will delete.

Comment: @vectory Don't delete your question. Questions and answers are not just here for the questioner alone.

Comment: @vectory: You might be thinking of [**Tambour Embroidery**](https://trc-leiden.nl/trc-needles/techniques/embroidery/general-embroidery/tambour-embroidery), but most native speakers wouldn't know about that anyway. To be honest though, if ***piping*** isn't the answer you wanted, I'm not convinced this is a proper question for ELL in the first place. We're not here to teach non-native speakers terms that aren't even familiar to most native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

The generic terms is military braiding/braid.

Here is a British site full of these items. But I think the terms are the same in AmE.

Their tagline says this:

> Military Uniform Braid, Lace, **Cord**, and Other Regalia Trimmings "What
>   the Professionals Use"

They seem to use braid and lace interchangeably.

[military heritage](http://www.militaryheritage.com/militarybraid.htm)

Answer (score 0):

An [aiguillette](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiguillette) (from Wikipedia) is the name of decorative cords with metal tips.

Similar cords are the fourragère and the Schützenschnur.